# Creating a first launch viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a "initial setup page" that is shown if the app is launched for the first time on the device.

I made it like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        NSLog(@"not first launch");
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;

    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];



        NSLog(@"first launch");

    }
}
```

Now I want to create a view controller and push to this view controller if it's the first time the app is launched.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new ViewController. Import the header in `appDelegate.h` file also create a instance variable of that class with name `initialViewController`.

Change your else condition like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
   {
       NSLog(@"not first launch");
       self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
       self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
   }
   else
   {
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

       self.initialViewController = [[InitialViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InitialViewController" bundle:nil];
       self.window.rootViewController = self.InitialViewController;
       NSLog(@"first launch");
   }
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: Ok looks great what would you suggest as best place to create the viewcontroller?

Comment: @user1805901: I didn't get you ! Which view Controller ?

Comment: @user1805901: With pleasure :)

Comment: @MidhunMP Hi, does this work only for Storyboards?  I cannot get it to work for my app that does not use Storyboards :S

Comment: @user3127576: No, actually I wrote this answer for xib files :)