# first time app is launched it will show the MKMapView instead of startviewcontroller

Tags: ios

I'm right now working on an fitness app and what i wanna do is that the first time the user starts the app it will directly go to the mkmapview and start first run, and when the user opens the application other times it will start att my starting view controller, how to set up this? i have read little about NSUserDefault but i can't get any idea how to get it to work, can somebody help me whit som ideas?

Comment: have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835475/creating-a-first-launch-viewcontroller

Comment: thanks.. gonna read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary   *)launchOptions
{
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasLaunched"]) {
        self.window.rootViewController = [[NormalViewController alloc] init];
   } else {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hasLaunched"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        self.window.rootViewController = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
   }
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: schould i put this code in the view controller that are my startviewcontroller?

Comment: this should be in your appdelegate